# R Shiny: saving full session with settings for log/debug purposes

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a shiny app, and as always, it is possible that something may crash  or return unexpected results from the database, etc. For this the idea is to implement a simple bug report in the app.

The basic idea here is a button with `shinyBS:::bsModal` popup, that gives the ability to write down the problem and log it/send it as an email.

However, it would be useful to also store the full session at the time of the submit for an easier debug. For example, so it could be possible to load it up and see the error.

Is this possible from a shiny app?  Are there tools/functions made for specifically this purpose? Since debugging shiny apps, in my experience, is quite more difficult than usual R code.

Comment: You can save the state of the app, including Input Parameters with: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html.

Comment: @BigDataScientist worth looking into, thanks.

Comment: Are there maybe any functions to dump the whole stdout of the previous console history to a file? One way would be to capture and discard (when not needed) stdout for every session, but it would be better if it's possible to do this retrospectivelly?

Comment: @BigDataScientist Although, I'm not sure this will work as intended when not on RStudio Server, as I'm running through dockerized simple ``runApp()``.